# Unity sprite mask shader

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader, mask

I have water and sun light on it. I want so sun's light be above one front wave. I have managed to do it, but it works only on PC, not on Android. What should I do so that worked on Android?

top picture-PC, bottom- Android:
[image: top picture-PC, bottom- Android]

Here is the shader's code for water:

```
Shader "Sprites/Stencil Mask"
{
 Properties
 {
     [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
     [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
 }

 SubShader
 {
     Tags
     {
         "Queue"="Transparent"
         "IgnoreProjector"="True"
         "RenderType"="Transparent"
         "PreviewType"="Plane"
         "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
     }

     Cull Off
     Lighting Off
     ZWrite Off
     Fog { Mode Off }
     Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

     Pass
     {
         Stencil
         {
             Ref 1
             Comp always
             Pass replace
         }

     CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag
         #pragma multi_compile DUMMY PIXELSNAP_ON
         #include "UnityCG.cginc"

         struct appdata_t
         {
             float4 vertex   : POSITION;
             float4 color    : COLOR;
             float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         struct v2f
         {
             float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
             fixed4 color    : COLOR;
             half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         fixed4 _Color;

         v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
         {
             v2f OUT;
             OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
             OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
             OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
             #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
             OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
             #endif

             return OUT;
         }

         sampler2D _MainTex;

         fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
         {
             fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
             if (c.a<0.1) discard;            //Most IMPORTANT working Code
             c.rgb *= c.a;
             return c;
         }
     ENDCG
     }
 }
  }
```

And this is for the sun's light:

```
Shader "Sprites/Stencil Draw In Mask"
{
Properties
{
    [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
}

SubShader
{
    Tags
    {
        "Queue"="Transparent+1"              //DON'T FORGET this must be drew later to catch Stencil Ref value.
        "IgnoreProjector"="True"
        "RenderType"="Transparent"
        "PreviewType"="Plane"
        "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
    }

    Cull Off
    Lighting Off
    ZWrite Off
    Fog { Mode Off }
    Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

    Pass
    {
        Stencil
        {
            Ref 1
            Comp Equal
        }

    CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile DUMMY PIXELSNAP_ON
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata_t
        {
            float4 vertex   : POSITION;
            float4 color    : COLOR;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
            fixed4 color    : COLOR;
            half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        fixed4 _Color;

        v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
        {
            v2f OUT;
            OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
            OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
            OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
            #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
            OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
            #endif

            return OUT;
        }

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
            c.rgb *= c.a;
            return c;
        }
    ENDCG
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working for you, but I've just tested this on Android (Galaxy S5) and it's working perfectly fine.

Thanks for providing the shader code though. This is currently the only working (and free) Sprite Stencil shader I've come across.